# PHP _POST with Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
    function sterge(id_user){
        console.log(id_user);
        var mesaj_post ='id_user=' + id_user;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'deleteStudent.php',
            data: mesaj_post,
            dataType: 'text',
            cache: false,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that in the PHP file called by function, POST is empty and I don't understand why. The parameter of the function is not empty/null, and script result is **SUCCESS**

PHP Code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['id_user']))
    echo $_POST['id_user'];
else
    echo "empty post";
?>
```

Can you help me fix it? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: `var mesaj_post ={'id_user': id_user};`

Comment: How do you determine that `$_POST` is empty?

Comment: @splash58 cleaner but won't change anything... string approach OP using is perfectly valid

Comment: @charlietfl the console likely shows 'succcccccccceeeeessss' and nothing else

Comment: @mplungjan not really obvious... the window reload won't let you see console very long

Comment: True, unless you record the response

Comment: @splash58 - same result.

Comment: @charlietfl - well first of all, in java id_user is not empty, i use console.log to check it. In PHP it is not going into if(isset...), it is going into else. If i remove else statement i get unidentified 'id_user'.

Comment: Remove the window.location.replace - it calls your php with a GET and no id_user

Comment: @mplungjan if you use opera it shows it :) just check the option :). Already tried to remove it, same result :)

Comment: problem is you reload `deleteStudent.php`... there will be no post data on that reload. Only on initial ajax request

Comment: @mplungjan `success:function(data){
                console.log(data+'succccccccccceeeeeessss');
                window.location.replace('deleteStudent.php');
            }` . *data* parameter is the one printed above in console log id student. So method displays 6succeeessss....

Comment: @mplungjan removed replace, still same result

Comment: *"So method displays 6succeeesss"* ... then it is working properly during ajax request. Not really clear where problem is.

Comment: removed replace in question

Comment: FIXED - looks like the form with the button was also doing a redirect. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

As **@charlietfl** first said in his comment, the replace was the problem. But not only that one. The **form** was also doing a replace.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I pointed out in my comment

*Remove the window.location.replace - it calls your php with a GET and no id_user*

Had you posted your form too, we could have seen you did not cancel the submission. I hope you did that with something like

```
$("#formID").on("submit",function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  $.post("deleteStudent.php",{ "id_user":$("#id_user").val() }, function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

of course this error occurs, you pass a string not josn object to correct this error you should do the following in javascript code :`mesaj_post ={'id_user': id_user};` :)

Comment: This is not correct. String used is perfectly valid and there is no such thing as  *json object*

Answer (score -1):

Try with this code this may do helpful for you

```
function sterge(id_user){
    console.log(id_user);
    var mesaj_post = {
        "id_user":id_user
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'deleteStudent.php',
        data: mesaj_post,
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```